# custom checkbox not working on multiple checkbox

Tags: html, css

Below is the snippet of my custom checkbox. What I want is to make it work (checked, unchecked stuff) multiple times without relying on id's on the input checkbox (input checkbox id is the reference of for attribute in the label). Is there any ways to do that? any help, suggestions, recommendations ,clues and ideas is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PS: refer unto my snippet below, you can see only one is working.

```css
.checkbox{display: table; border: 1px solid red;}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none !important;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    cursor:pointer;
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAmCAIAAACphTeFAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAANhJREFUeNpi7Dlmz0AWYGIgF4zqHNU5qnNU50jRqS3qAWezEKmHnYXHX71Fls8AyL76egexOoHawrQmiHGrAPVAtBGlk49dAmgbUNvxJwuOPV6AxbVAlzz+dAFNG1AD0DagnTvudMBtQwkhoLYw7QkeKhWY2oAMTG0IO4G2AeUgQQdUBwlGR4UcIGPVtYJXX+9g+gLhWrgGkEEfLwDt//nnCy5t6CEE1wxEQA0bb9Z8+vkCV8ihhy1EsyiXCtA2oJ14whxLrAA1AwMTvzacqY+gtiGXywACDABDcVluuHVmiAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
background-position: 19px 0px; 
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {

background-position: 0px 19px;

}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" checked style="display: none;"/>
<label for="c1"><span></span></label>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" checked style="display: none;"/>
<label for="c1"><span></span></label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Set unique IDS and get it done easily!

Comment: as for my requirements (php loop stuff) can't do that like that.

Comment: You can do that! you might have unique numbers to your loop as always there will be an index! you can use that

Comment: @JuliverGalleto, what you can't do? Set unique ID?! Why? Anyway, you must do it, if you want that page works properly....

Comment: i display the checkbox through pjp loop (pull data from database and display it)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak: is there other way than that?

Comment: @JuliverGalleto I guess there is no other way. And IDs must be always unique! you need to take that into practice!

Comment: You have loop, what is problem? It is even easier to set unique id's that way (no hard coding).....

Comment: i see. there's no other way then ill use unique id's from database then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set unique **IDs** As Ids must be unique in a DOM, Make sure your `<label for=''>` must be having same ID as it's relevant input.

```css
.checkbox{display: table; border: 1px solid red;}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none !important;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    cursor:pointer;
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAAmCAIAAACphTeFAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAANhJREFUeNpi7Dlmz0AWYGIgF4zqHNU5qnNU50jRqS3qAWezEKmHnYXHX71Fls8AyL76egexOoHawrQmiHGrAPVAtBGlk49dAmgbUNvxJwuOPV6AxbVAlzz+dAFNG1AD0DagnTvudMBtQwkhoLYw7QkeKhWY2oAMTG0IO4G2AeUgQQdUBwlGR4UcIGPVtYJXX+9g+gLhWrgGkEEfLwDt//nnCy5t6CEE1wxEQA0bb9Z8+vkCV8ihhy1EsyiXCtA2oJ14whxLrAA1AwMTvzacqY+gtiGXywACDABDcVluuHVmiAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
background-position: 19px 0px; 
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {

background-position: 0px 19px;

}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" checked style="display: none;"/>
<label for="c1"><span></span></label>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" checked style="display: none;"/>
<label for="c2"><span></span></label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: as for my requirements (php loop stuff) can't do that like that

Comment: @JuliverGalleto  
You can do that! you might have unique numbers to your loop as always there will be an index! you can use that

Comment: is there any other way than that?

Comment: i see. there's no other way then ill use unique id's from database then. Thank you!